# how to update/assigning new values to elements of a DatasetDict outside the loop (for cycle) in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tensorflow, arraylist

I have a dataset of images, I resize every image of the dataset and then re-assign the i-th element of the dataset with the resized_image. I'm doing this with the following code:

```
for i in range(0,len(dataset['train'])): #len(dataset['train'])

  ex = dataset['train'][i] #i
  image = ex['image']
  image = image.convert("RGB") # <class 'PIL.Image.Image'> <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=500x333 at 0x7F84F1948150>
  image_resized = image.resize(size_to_resize) # <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=224x224 at 0x7F84F17885D0>
  
  dataset['train'][i]['image'] = image_resized
```

the point is that out of the for loop, the

```
dataset['train'][Iterator]['image'] # where iterator=0,1,2,3,4...
```

give me back the i-th image not resized!

Comment: what's the type of `dataset` and its `train` field/column?

Comment: If dataset is a dict of dicts your code looks fine. Have you tried adding a print statement in the foor loop to output the image size after resizing to check that it actually works as intended?

Comment: @Marat the dataset has the following structure:
DatasetDict({
    train: Dataset({
        features: ['image', 'label'],
        num_rows: 20580
    })
})

Comment: @ffrosch the structure is in the above comment. I tried to print all the images resized inside the for loop and all the have the right size. Once out of the for loop the size is the "original" one, so images aren't re-sized. Seems like that the "assignment" isn't a real assignment but more a kind of pointer (???)

Comment: From which library/module do the `DatasetDict` and `Dataset` classes originate?

Comment: Ok, I think @Marat found the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alas, you can't change it inplace.

[`DatasetDict`](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/v2.3.2/en/package_reference/main_classes#datasets.DatasetDict) is backed by [Arrow tables](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/tables.html), which are [immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65845694/how-to-update-data-in-pyarrow-table)

Comment: That is what I was thinking!!! Thanks for your answer.